# Finding integer coprime to $x$ of given form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $x$ be a positive integer which is odd, not prime and not a power of $3$. I experimentally observed the following: There always appears to exist some integer $1<y<x$ which is one more than a multiple of some prime factor of $x$ such that for every integer $z$, either $zy\equiv z\mod x$, or $zy^2\equiv zy\mod x$, or $zy^3\not\equiv z\mod x$.

Anyway, this is just to give some context. It all boiled down to proving the following (which may be stronger, but at least it is easier to grasp):

> If $x$ is a positive integer which is odd and not a power of $3$, then
> we find some prime factor $p\geq 5$ of $x$ and some integer $0<a<x$ for
> which $a^2p^2+3ap+3$ is coprime to $x$.

I unfortunately have no intuition for this problem. I'd be happy to hear some opinions on it; even small comments like "This seems unlikely" are already of high value!

Comment: Since the statement is obivously true of every prime power, it would be sufficient to show that if the statement is true for coprime $x, y$, then it is true for $xy$,

Comment: Also, do we want $a < x$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, I added it. Thanks.

Comment: If my computer program is correct, the $a^2 p^2 + 3ap + 3$ conjecture holds for every $x$ less than 100,000,000.

Comment: "There always appears to exist some integer $1<y<x$ which is one more than a multiple of some factor of $x$" Come to think of it, isn't that true of all integers $1 < y < x$, since they're all 1 greater than a multiple of 1?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thank you, I actually meant "prime divisors."

Comment: I suppose as long as I'm being pedantic, this now fails when $x$ is prime, as there is no $1 < y < x$ that is one more than a multiple of a prime divisor of $x$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, also true. This was actually an assumption in the beginning, but I removed it as I thought I didn't need it... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be the exponent of $3$ in $x$'s prime factorization, i.e., $3^k \mid x$ but $3^{k+1} \nmid x$. Also, have $p_1 \ge 5$ be any other prime factor of $x$. Using $a = \frac{x}{3^k(p_1)}$ then gives

$$y = a^{2}p_1^{2} + 3ap_1 + 3 = \left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right)^2 + 3\left(\frac{x}{3^k}\right) + 3$$

If $3$ is a factor of $x$, then since $3$ doesn't divide the first term but divides the remaining $2$ terms, we get that $3 \nmid y$. Also, any other prime factor $p_i \ge 5$ of $x$ divides the first $2$ terms of $y$ but doesn't divide the third term of $3$, so $p_i \nmid y$. Thus, no prime factor of $x$ divides $y$, which means that $y$ is coprime to $x$.

Comment: Incredible. Thank you!

Comment: Your $a$ in particular satisfies $0<a\leq x/p_1$. In case $x$ is divisible by $3$, we have strict inequalities. Is there a way to obtain strict inequalities also when $x$ is not divisible by $3$?

Comment: @Zuy You can't get strict inequalities in all cases, such as when $x = p_1$ since then you would have $0 \lt a \lt x/p_1 = 1$. For the other cases where $x$ is composite, I suspect that most, if not all, of these other values of $x$ would have an $a$ within strict inequalities (especially if $p_1$ is the smallest prime factor of $x$ so $\frac{x}{p_1}$ is larger than when dealing with other prime factors of $x$), but I don't know offhand how to prove that. Nonetheless, I will think about it and let you know if I determine anything useful. Also, you may consider asking a new question about this.